# "Allowed memory size" problem

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, memory

I duplicated a wordpress website. On the new domain, the TYPES plugin causes big problems. I get several "Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted" error messages. They show up when I try to do the following:

- clicking on "Pages": Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /WWWROOT/234568/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/types/embedded/classes/loader.php on line 62
- when I want to add posts in Custom Post Types:
  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 122880 bytes) in /WWWROOT/234568/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php on line 847

I already tried to solve this problem by following these instructions here: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/allowed-memory-size-exhausted-what-does-that-mean But nothing has helped.

My host provider told me I need to increase my RAM. It is set to 64 MB at the moment. BUT: At my old domain (same host provider) RAM is also set to 64 MB, and here everythings works fine. Why does it not work at my new domain? It's exactly the same website, just duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your php settings, there is some script that is wither bad configured and it is eating up more resources that it should. Consider updating your plugins, and see what is happening with the "types" plugin.

On your first error ( clicking pages ), the types plugin is where it stops. In the second, you are also trying to do something related to wordpress cusom post types.

Try disabling the plugin and see if the problem is gone. Try deleting the plugin and reinstalling it, or see if there are any settings that should have been changed.

Comment: disabling the plugin helps, yes, but then my taxonomies that i created with "types" are not displayed anymore. if i re-install it: will my taxonomies be kept or deleted?

Comment: This depends on how is the plugin built. Make sure you backup your database and files and then try to delete it and create it again. Maybe the fact that there is maybe some fault data migrated from the old host. Go trough your database and try to find if there is any data saved with the old paths. If it works to delete and install it again, it might worth it to manually re-add all taxonomies than to keep this plugin to constantly overload your website.